# Transitions coupled to different baths in quantum thermodynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I don't understand the general assumptions made during the separation of a **single environment** of the open system represented by the energy levels into **two baths** at two temperatures in the diagram below.

Is it assumed that the frequency $\omega_c$ is absent in the spectrum of the hot bath, $\omega_h$ is absent in the cold bath and $\nu$ absent in both?

[image: wiki: Quantum_heat_engines_and_refrigerators]

This is how I picture it when the reservoirs are photon baths: 
[image]

Is this corrent? Are these conditions the same for phonon baths, i.e. excitation by collisions?